# Allow nginx to read docker.sock

Tags: nginx, docker

In order to monitor my docker containers, I've decided to expose docker remote API through nginx by the following rule:

```
server {
    listen 1234;
    server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/var/run/docker.sock;
    }
}
```

But in the `nginx.error` file, I get the following error:

```
connect() to unix:/var/run/docker.sock failed (13: Permission denied
```

The reason is that docker.sock is under the ownership of `docker` group while nginx is running in `www-data` group.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> The reason is that docker.sock is under the ownership of docker group
>   while nginx is running in www-data group.
>
> What is the best way to solve this problem?

For this issue you can add `user` under which `nginx` running to `docker` group.

```
usermod -a -G www-data,docker user
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open the http socket in the daemon by adding the following text to the ExecStart in the daemon config file:

```
-H <ip address>:2375
```

You can find the location of the configuration file in the output of the command:

```
systemctl status docker
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set permission for docker socket:

```
sudo chmod a+r /var/run/docker.sock
```